# How to read a global property file in a class?

Tags: java, internationalization, struts2

I am reading a struts2 tutorial on the following url.

http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/message-resource-files.html

it explains how to read a value of a property key in a view file, but it doesn't explain how to read property values in an action class or in a model class.

How do I read a value of a property key in an action or a model class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the method `ActionSupport.getText(String)`. For example :

**messages.properties**

```
foo.bar=foobar
```

**struts.xml**

```
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="messages" />
```

**Action class**

```
public class TestAction extends ActionSupport {

    public void method() {

        getText("foo.bar");

    }
}
```

---

> @Moon : what if I'm not extending ActionSupport?

For classes not extending `ActionSupport`, use the following  (**during run time of Struts2**) :

```
ActionSupport actionSupport = new ActionSupport();
actionSupport.getText("foo.bar");
```

Comment: // what if I'm not extending ActionSupport?

Comment: If there is a good reason for you to not extend `ActionSupport`, then take a look in `ActionSupport` and implement what it's doing for `getText`. It comes from the `TextProvider` interface. Otherwise, extend `ActionSupport`.